# Splitting string but leave inner strings intact?

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have a string that looks like this `'a,b,"c,d",e,"f,g,h"'`.

I would like to be able to split this string on `,` but leave encapsulated strings intact getting the following output : `["a","b","c,d","e","f,g,h"]`.

Is there a way to do this without having to parse the string char by char ?

Comment: is `a,b"c,d",e,"f,g,h"` a valid javascript string?

Comment: is your input a,b"c,d",e,"f,g,h". or a,b,"c,d",e,"f,g,h". I mean do u have a ',' after b

Comment: @Hitmands yes it is

Comment: so this: `'a,b"c,d",e,"f,g,h"'` ? Update your question because is confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a match of the strings, then map the matches and replace any `"` in the elements:

```js
let f = 'a,b"c,d",e,"f,g,h"';
let matches = f.match(/\w+|(["]).*?\1/g);

let res = matches.map(e => e.replace(/"/g, ''));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. This answer suits my needs and i will mark it as the accepted answer